# Unable to find SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" (Angular)

Tags: angular

I am very new to Angular and I am having trouble in displaying the data from PHP.

I have a view_property.php file which calls out the data from the property table such as below:
[image]

I assume that the database connection is ok since the console log shows all the details from the property table comes out perfectly such as below:
[image]
[image]

Problem is that I cannot find the syntax error. Because I am not sure whether its occurring because of the json_encode in the PHP file or is it because of Angular.

Here is my property.ts

```
export class Property 
{
    constructor
    (
        id: number,
        name:  String,
        price:  number,
        address: String,
        nearby_places: String,
        size: String,
        bedroom: number,
        bathroom: number,
        carpark: String,
        facilities: String,
        furnishing: String,
        manager_id: number,
        property_status: String
    ){} 
}
```

Here is my view-property.component.html.

```
  <tr *ngFor="let property of allproperty; let i =index;">
          <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
          <td>{{property.id}}</td>
          <td>{{property.name}}</td>
          <td>$ {{property.price}}</td>
          <td>{{property.address}}</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="getNavigation('view', property.id)">View</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="getNavigation('update', property.id)">Edit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteProperty('', property.id)">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Here is my view-property.component.ts.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CrudService} from '../../services/crud.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { Property } from 'src/app/property';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-property',
  templateUrl: './view-property.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-property.component.css']
})
export class ViewPropertyComponent implements OnInit 
{

    public allproperty: any = [];

    constructor(private crudService: CrudService, private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.loadProperty();
    }

    loadProperty(){
      this.crudService.getProperty().subscribe(
          propertyData => {
            this.allproperty = propertyData;
          }
      );
    }

    deleteProperty(link, id){
      this.crudService.deleteProperty(id).subscribe(result => {
        window.location.reload();
        this.router.navigate([link]);
      });
    }

    getNavigation(link, id){
        if(id === ''){
            this.router.navigate([link]);
        } else {
            this.router.navigate([link + '/' + id]);
        }
    }

  }
```

Please point out to me where is the syntax error. Your guidance is really appreciated.

Comment: The answer is in the question. Just look at the body of the response. It starts with `Connection to database successfull!`. That's not valid JSON. Fix your server so that it doesn't send such string to the output.

Comment: when send request to Api, you should handle it by return status code and avoid returning such this string, because you should return valid json in Api

Comment: @JBNizet : thanks a lot Sir. I removed the echo "connection successful" from the PHP file. and the details from the database come out.

Comment: @KenanaReda : thanks for the advice.. I will do so.. it is a valuable info to me.